# multipile 8bit registers connected to the same output (VHDL)

Tags: vhdl, ram, digital-logic

I create a 64bytes RAM using two 3bit address registers and cross bar of the 3 bit registers using two 3to8 decoders. Here is the VHDL code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ram88 is
  port(a : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
       s0: in std_logic;
       s1: in std_logic;
       s:  in std_logic;
       e:  in std_logic;
       io_in: in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
       io_out:out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));

end ram88;

architecture behavior of ram88 is

  component reg3 is
    port( a : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
          ss,e : in std_logic; --st and enable
          b : out std_logic_vector (2 downto 0));
  end component;

  component reg8 is
    port( a : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
          ss,e : in std_logic; --st and enable
          b : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
  end component;

  component decod8 is
    port( a : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
          b : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
  end component;

  signal e1 : std_logic := '1';
  signal l0, l1 : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
  signal ll0, ll1 : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
  type arr2d is array (7 downto 0, 7 downto 0) of std_logic;  
  signal andij, fin_s, fin_e : arr2d;

begin

  e1 <= '1';

  reg0: reg3 port map ( a => a, ss => s0, e => e1, b => l0);
  reg1: reg3 port map ( a => a, ss => s1, e => e1, b => l1);
  decod0: decod8 port map(a => l0, b => ll0);
  decod1: decod8 port map(a => l1, b => ll1);

  mem_blks_ii:
  for ii in 0 to 7 generate
    mem_blks_jj:
    for jj in 0 to 7 generate
      andij(ii,jj) <= ll0(ii) and ll1(jj);
      fin_s(ii,jj) <= andij(ii,jj) and s;
      fin_e(ii,jj) <= andij(ii,jj) and e;
      regij: reg8 port map(a=> io_in, ss=> fin_s(ii,jj), e => fin_e(ii,jj), b => io_out);
    end generate mem_blks_jj;
  end generate mem_blks_ii;


end behavior;
```

Then I use the following test unit for simulation. It sets the value 00000001 at memory address 000x000. At the end, it retrieves the value by setting the enable signal:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ram88_bench is

end ram88_bench;

architecture behavior of ram88_bench is

  component ram88
  port(a : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
       s0: in std_logic;
       s1: in std_logic;
       s:  in std_logic;
       e:  in std_logic;
       io_in: in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
       io_out:out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
  end component;

  signal abar : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
  signal s0bar, s1bar, sbar, ebar:  std_logic;
  signal io_in_bar, io_out_bar: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);

begin

  ram0: ram88 port map(a=>abar, s0=> s0bar, s1=> s1bar
                       , s=> sbar, e=> ebar
                       , io_in => io_in_bar, io_out=> io_out_bar);

  process
  begin

    -- set (0,1) for access point in memory
    abar <= "000";
    s0bar <= '1';
    s1bar <= '0';
    wait for 2 fs;
    s0bar <= '0';

    abar <= "000";
    s1bar <= '1';
    wait for 2 fs;
    s1bar <= '0';

    -- store the value ...
    ebar <= '1';
    sbar <= '1';
    io_in_bar <= "00000001";
    wait for 2 fs;
    sbar <= '0';

    ---- temporary clear the value before retrieval
    --sbar <= '0';
    --ebar <= '0';
    ---- io_in_bar <= "00000000";    
    --wait for 2 fs;

    --retrieve the value ????
    ebar <= '1';
    sbar <= '0';
    wait for 6 fs;

    wait;

  end process;

end behavior;
```

The problem is that the value in io_out_bar is forced to unknowns "0X" instead of expected 00000001 at the end of simulation! I couldn't figure out why but I guess since all 8bit RAM registers are connected to the same output, it can't be determined which one is the real value we need to retrieve. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Select one using a multiplexer. An alternative is to use tristate logic, but that isn't valid in any modern FPGA I know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're question isn't a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and it helps to demonstrate the solution.  Some quick and dirty entities for instantiation:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity reg3 is
    port (
        a:      in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        ss,e:   in  std_logic;
        b:      out std_logic_vector (2 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of reg3 is
begin
    b <= a when ss = '1' and e = '1';
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity decod8 is
    port (
        a:      in  std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
        b:      out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of decod8 is
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
begin
    process (a)
        variable idx:   natural range 0 to 7;
    begin
        idx := to_integer(unsigned(a));
        b <= (others => '0');
        b(idx) <= '1';
    end process;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity reg8 is
    port (
        a:      in  std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        ss,e:   in  std_logic;
        b:      out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture foo of reg8 is
begin
    b <= a when ss = '1' and e = '1';
end architecture;
```

> ... I guess since all 8bit RAM registers are connected to the same output, it can't be determined which one is the real value we need to retrieve. How can I resolve this issue?

You surmise correctly, all *64* 8 bit registers drive `io_out`.

The idea here is to select only one at a time according to the index supplied to the RAM.  The example uses the same write addresses from the `l0` and `l1` latches, used to select 1 of 64 8 bit registers for output.

It's done purely behaviorally here, but could be done with instantiated multiplexers (selectors):

```
architecture behavior of ram88 is

  component reg3 is
    port( a : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
          ss,e : in std_logic; --st and enable
          b : out std_logic_vector (2 downto 0));
  end component;

  component reg8 is
    port( a : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
          ss,e : in std_logic; --st and enable
          b : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
  end component;

  component decod8 is
    port( a : in std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
          b : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
  end component;

  signal e1 : std_logic := '1';
  signal l0, l1 : std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
  signal ll0, ll1 : std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
  type arr2d is array (7 downto 0, 7 downto 0) of std_logic;  
  signal andij, fin_s, fin_e : arr2d;
  type mux is array (7 downto 0, 7 downto 0) of    -- ADDED
              std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
  signal mux88: mux;                               -- ADDED
  signal idxii, idxjj:  natural range 0 to 7;      -- ADDED
  use ieee.numeric_std.all;                        -- ADDED

begin

  e1 <= '1';

  idxii <= to_integer(unsigned(l0));              -- ADDED
  idxjj <= to_integer(unsigned(l1));              -- ADDED

  reg0: reg3 port map ( a => a, ss => s0, e => e1, b => l0);
  reg1: reg3 port map ( a => a, ss => s1, e => e1, b => l1);
  decod0: decod8 port map(a => l0, b => ll0);
  decod1: decod8 port map(a => l1, b => ll1);

  mem_blks_ii:
  for ii in 0 to 7 generate
    mem_blks_jj:
    for jj in 0 to 7 generate
      andij(ii,jj) <= ll0(ii) and ll1(jj);
      fin_s(ii,jj) <= andij(ii,jj) and s;
      fin_e(ii,jj) <= andij(ii,jj) and e;
    -- regij: reg8 port map(a=> io_in, ss=> fin_s(ii,jj), e => fin_e(ii,jj), b => io_out);   -- CHANGED 
    regij: reg8 port map(a=> io_in, ss=> fin_s(ii,jj), e => fin_e(ii,jj), b => mux88(ii,jj));        -- CHANGED 
    end generate mem_blks_jj;
  end generate mem_blks_ii;

  io_out <= mux88(idxii, idxjj);    -- ADDED READBACK MUX

end behavior;
```

And that gives:

[image: ram88_bench_fixed.png]

RAM read back.

The 8 by 8 by 8-bit std_logic_vector value has one of 64 b-bit values selected by the two added indexes. If you were to construct it from instantiated components, synthesize and count where all the logic gates are you'd find it's about the same size as the latches used for RAM and their fan-in buffers, and quite a bit bigger than the write steering logic.

Comment: Thank you! Very comprehensive answer!